# Changing perspective of one element affects the position of other element

Tags: css

I have a trinomial cube which can build out of 27 elements. The perspective of each piece can be changed by dblclick. Page is divided into two divs: left (grey cointainer)- which contains pieces of the cube; and right (white area) - where cube can be assambled by the user.
The problem is that changing perspective of one element on the left affects the position of elements already arranged on the right.
For example, in my snippet you will see that if the last piece (id = 4) is placed on the right and you try to change the perspective of black elements the position of the #4 piece will change.

I want to sparate divs or make elements non-relative to prevent such behaviour. How I can do it?

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#1" ).draggable();
} );

$( function() {
    $( "#2" ).draggable();
} );

$( function() {
    $( "#3" ).draggable();
} );

$( function() {
    $( "#4" ).draggable();
} );

$( function() {
    $( "#21" ).draggable();
} );

// Changing perspective
var images1 = [
    "https://i.postimg.cc/XNy5t0Fq/1-2.gif",
    "https://i.postimg.cc/8C5J48N1/1-3.gif",
    "https://i.postimg.cc/fLS34xVp/2-1.gif",
];
var imageIndex = 0;
var imagesTag2 = document.getElementById("2")
var imagesTag3 = document.getElementById("3")
var imagesTag21 = document.getElementById("21")

imagesTag2.addEventListener("dblclick", function(event){
    imageIndex = (++imageIndex % 3);
    event.target.src = images1[imageIndex];
});

imagesTag3.addEventListener("dblclick", function(event){
    imageIndex = (++imageIndex % 3);
    event.target.src = images1[imageIndex];
});

imagesTag21.addEventListener("dblclick", function(event){
    imageIndex = (++imageIndex % 3);
    event.target.src = images1[imageIndex];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Trinomial Cube </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="trinominal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="trinominal.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page" style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: auto;"> 
    <div class="cotainer" style="flex-direction: column; width: 45%; background-color: grey;">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/85x6sy8T/1-1.gif" id="1">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XNy5t0Fq/1-2.gif" id="2">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XNy5t0Fq/1-2.gif" id="3">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XNy5t0Fq/1-2.gif" id="21">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sDdWr09c/1-4.gif" id="4">
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropzone" style="width: 55%;">
      <!-- An area for the elements to be arranged --> 
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```